# Orientdb query for getting all vertices connected by edge of specyfic type

Tags: sql, orientdb

I'm looking for query that will return vertices that are connected to specific vertex (with known rid) by specific edge class, problem is that the connected vertices can have different classes

[image: my graph]

in this example i need query that will give me #68:0, #72:5.
What I need exactly, is the properties data for them and in orient studio browse mode it returns only links to them [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onXKE.png)

Answer (score 4):

Given a specific vertex rid and edge class you can use the out() function to get adjacent outgoing vertices and the expand() function to include all fields:

```
SELECT expand(out("has_conditionsElement")) FROM #44:62
```

You can also use in() for incoming vertices:

```
SELECT expand(in("has_conditionsElement")) FROM #44:62
```

Or both() for all directions:

```
SELECT expand(both("has_conditionsElement")) FROM #44:62
```

Source:

[SQL-Functions > out()](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Functions.html#out)

[SQL-Functions > in()](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Functions.html#in)

[SQL-Functions > both()](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Functions.html#both)

[SQL-Functions > expand()](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Functions.html#expand)

Comment: ok, maybe i dont know how orient exactly works (or just studio), I already tried this, but only thing that i got in browse mode, is word "out" and links to connected objects, no properties data at all (in graph mode no results at all) - is this normalisation problem, and I will need to fetch them separately ? (ok I see now that my question was not precise enough)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include all fields, I hope this helps :)